xfce4-terminal cannot be killed
From a Python program, I start xfce4-terminal as a subprocess. When calling .terminate(), xfce4-terminal is still there. Not nice. So I tried to kill it more abruptly - surprisingly, the corresponding process with corresponding PID is not there anymore... Some ancient and dangerous black magic is happening there (?). See by yourself:
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc=subprocess.Popen(["xfce4-terminal"])
>>> #you should see the terminal is started...
>>> proc.terminate()
>>> #it is still there, alive and kicking...
>>> import os
>>> os.kill(proc.pid, 9) #let's try something more radical (SIGKILL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process
>>> # WTF???

I was curious of this behaviour so I reproduced the issue in bash, it has nothing to do with Python's subprocess of course:
(base) [matias@kashyyyk bec]$ xfce4-terminal &
[1] 167148
(base) [matias@kashyyyk bec]$ kill 167148
bash: kill: (167148) - No such process

(the terminal is still there)
I am really puzzled. What's going on?

Cannot reproduce the bash example, it is killed successfully, both with/without -9. Could you please check something like ps -ef | grep xfce to see if the pid changed somehow?

If xfce4-terminal were a wrapper script that launched the terminal itself as a separate process, then that would explain it disappearing before the terminal itself does.  You might even have your own such script interposed between you and an xcfe4-terminal provided by the system.  The command type xfce4-terminal would be a place to start for checking that out.

I am running Manjaro, there is no script in between AFAIK: type xfce4-terminal gives /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal and file on it gives ELF executable...

Something new: I found --disable-server command line argument... If I disable the "server", everything works as expected @RibomBalt

That's interesting. Just being curious, is there any other xfce4-terminal instances running on the same desktop environment? Though this is pure guess there might be some crazy session-reuse phenomenon here with the dbus server, and if you disable the dbus server the new terminal becomes standalone. Maybe pstree to see the parent processes of bash in that not-closed xfce4-terminal would help to diagnose this. @mguijarr

Well that's similar to the wrapper script idea, then.  If you run xfce4-terminal without --disable-server then (under the correct conditions) it will just cause the new terminal window to be opened by another existing process, instead of itself acting as the terminal's process.  In that case, it will exit quickly while the terminal window persists. And you've already discovered a workaround.

fyi - works as expected on:: linux mint (20.2) , xfce4-terminal 0.8.10 (Xfce 4.16) ,
python 3.12.2 , GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)  . NB: NO other xfce* processes running
